# MySQL split multivalued strings from same table in different column into new table

Tags: mysql, split, insert-into

I want to split *multi valued* strings which are from one table into a new table consisting of a primary key and the split strings result.

Example strings:

> table1.field1 (primary key) = 100 , table1.field2 = 'abc,def,ghi'

In the new table (table2), the result should be like this:

```
         **column1** **column2**
**row1**     100        'abc' 
**row2**     100        'def' 
**row3**     100        'ghi'
**row4**     etc         etc
```

I know how to split table1.field2, but since the data was so large, I need to insert the result automatically into table2. If I do it manually, it will take so long. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using a prepared statement:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS concatenatedVals;
CREATE TABLE concatenatedVals(`key` INTEGER UNSIGNED, concatenatedValue CHAR(255));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS splitVals;
CREATE TABLE splitVals(`key` INTEGER UNSIGNED, splitValue CHAR(255));

INSERT INTO concatenatedVals VALUES (100, 'abc,def,ghi'), (200, 'jkl,mno,pqr');
SELECT * FROM concatenatedVals;

SET @VKey := '';
SET @VExec := (SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO splitVals VALUES', TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', @VKey:= `key`, ', \'', REPLACE(concatenatedValue, ',', CONCAT('\'), (', @VKey, ', \'')), '\'),') SEPARATOR '')), ';') FROM concatenatedVals);

PREPARE stmt FROM @VExec;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT * FROM splitVals;
```

Outputs:

```
SELECT * FROM splitVals;
+------+------------+
| key  | splitValue |
+------+------------+
|  100 | abc        |
|  100 | def        |
|  100 | ghi        |
|  200 | jkl        |
|  200 | mno        |
|  200 | pqr        |
+------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Regarding the question, how can I account for scenarios where the number of rows in my source table means the prepared statement exceeds the max-concat length, see the following example. As this uses a `WHILE` loop it must be inside a stored procedure. This could be adapted to allow table names and column names as arguments using further `CONCAT`AND prepared statements to build up and execute commands dynamically. For now however, please change the table and column names from those in my example to match your data and it should work fine.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS concatenatedVals;
CREATE TABLE concatenatedVals(`key` INTEGER UNSIGNED, concatenatedValue CHAR(255));

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS splitVals;
CREATE TABLE splitVals(`key` INTEGER UNSIGNED, splitValue CHAR(255));

INSERT INTO concatenatedVals VALUES (100, 'abc,def,ghi'), (200, 'jkl,mno,pqr'),(300, 'abc,def,ghi'), (400, 'jkl,mno,pqr'),(500, 'abc,def,ghi'), (600, 'jkl,mno,pqr'),(700, 'abc,def,ghi'), (800, 'jkl,mno,pqr'),(900, 'abc,def,ghi'), (1000, 'jkl,mno,pqr');
SELECT * FROM concatenatedVals;

DELIMITER $

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS loopStringSplit$

CREATE PROCEDURE loopStringSplit()
BEGIN

    DECLARE VKeyMaxLength, VConcatValMaxLength, VFixedCommandLength, VVariableCommandLength, VSelectLimit, VRowsToProcess, VRowsProcessed INT;

    SET VFixedCommandLength = CHAR_LENGTH(CONCAT('INSERT INTO splitVals VALUES;'));
    SET VKeyMaxLength = (SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(`key`)) FROM concatenatedVals);
    SET VConcatValMaxLength = (SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(concatenatedValue)) FROM concatenatedVals);
    SET VVariableCommandLength = CHAR_LENGTH('(,\'\')');

    SET VSelectLimit = FLOOR((@@group_concat_max_len - VFixedCommandLength) / (VKeyMaxLength + VConcatValMaxLength + VVariableCommandLength));

    SET VRowsToProcess := (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM concatenatedVals);
    SET VRowsProcessed = 0;

    SELECT VRowsProcessed, VRowsToProcess, VSelectLimit;
    WHILE VRowsProcessed < VRowsToProcess DO

        SET @VKey := '';
        SET @VExec := (SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO splitVals VALUES', TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(', @VKey:= `key`, ', \'', REPLACE(concatenatedValue, ',', CONCAT('\'), (', @VKey, ', \'')), '\'),') SEPARATOR '')), ';') FROM (SELECT * FROM concatenatedVals LIMIT VRowsProcessed, VSelectLimit) A);

        SELECT @VExec;

        PREPARE stmt FROM @VExec;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

        SET VRowsProcessed = VRowsProcessed + VSelectLimit;

        SELECT CONCAT('Processed rows: ', VRowsProcessed);

    END WHILE;

END$

DELIMITER ;

CALL loopStringSplit();

SELECT * FROM splitVals;
```

Regards,

James

Comment: by the way, I tried to implement your code in larger data and got this error Warning Code : 1260
Row 14 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT(), I try to use group_concat_max_len but still not work, do you have any better solution? thanks before.

Comment: I'm out the office at the moment, will code something up this evening and add it to the answer

Comment: Would be helpful to know what kind of data volumes your dealing with if possible - is it above 100000 rows? If so by what power of ten? Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but how much? Millions or billions? Due to the session variable length limitation we need to use a loop, much over 10^7 rows and it would be better to look outside of pure SQL unless long runtime is acceptable

Comment: ah, sorry not giving a clear answer. My data is about 500000 rows

Comment: @user3698011, see an updated answer, apologies for the delay.

Comment: It's ok, James. I followed your code and a little modified it into my data, it's working! Thank you so much 4 helping.